# How to get event for internet connect and disconnect

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, go

I want to perform some operations when the internet is a disconnected. How can I get that event without an HTTP call? Earlier I used to continuously hit the URL after some interval. Is there any better solution than this?

Comment: Implement [INetworkEvents::NetworkConnectivityChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetworkevents-networkconnectivitychanged) and wire it up. You're going to have find out, how to implement and access COM interfaces in Go.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is no other way. Chose a faster endpoint(like google), don't use dns address use plain ip so it will not try to resolve it. Also send a head request, so the you don't wait for the body.

```
res, err := http.Head("http://216.58.192.142")
```